# How to install latest grub2 version on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: grub2

The version of grub2 on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is `1.99-21ubuntu3.19`, as shown below:

```
me@D0:~$ grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 1.99-21ubuntu3.19
```

How can I install the latest version of grub2, like the one installed on Ubuntu 16.04, on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Comment: May I ask Why do you need latest grub?

Comment: @Anwar I need some added features to latest versions of `grub2` regarding `freebsd` support

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Upgrading

Comment: @ElderGeek I need to upgrade from grub2 `1.99-21ubuntu3.19` to grub2 `2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.3 `

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you truly feel the need to update grub2 from v.199 to 2.02 I suggest that you upgrade to either trusty or xenial. This will have the added benefit of providing you with a system that will be in support for over a year instead of under a year.

Source:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=grub

Comment: Would it be risky to build and install grub2 `2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.3 ` by the source code?

Comment: Do you really wish to coninue using a version which will be out of support come April? Like all endeavors, it's only risky if you don't backup

Comment: I have some enterprise software which I'm not quite sure if they would work with 14.04/16.04.

Comment: Like all endeavors, it's only risky if you don't backup

Comment: Elder Geek is right, backup and test if all the software works, restore and file bugs or support request for that "enterprise" software if it doesn't.

Comment: @ElderGeek I ended up doing a release upgrade from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS. Now my grub version is 2.02 (>1.99) as I wanted. Looks like my software work fine. The only point is that my graphics hardware is old and graphical desktop environment on 14.04 LTS is very slow. But it doesn't matter, I use `TWM` anyway.